# Force ReSharper install in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to enforce the installation of ReSharper for Visual Studio? Like, to the extreme of build blocking on a developer if it doesn't exist?

We're using VS 2019 and ReSharper Ultimate 2019.1.2.

Comment: No, why would you even want to do this and how would you enforce that the developer would use it? Have more code reviews if you want to ensure code quality.

Comment: @PiersMyers valid question. this was prompted by a team meeting yesterday and thought i would ask. our team has adopted resharper, but some were resistant to it and refused to install. so i figured i would ask.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to force this tool on all the developers, ReSharper is a great tool but it can have a big impact on performance which they may not like. You could take a look at the command line tools (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_Command_Line_Tools.html) and incorporate them in to your build process.